# vs 2008 no debugging

Tags: visual-studio

my debugging in visual studio 2008 has stopped working , the debugger doesn't hit any breakpoint . what should i do?

Comment: Are you running in release mode?

Comment: Clean -> Re-build -> Run

Answer (score 1):

Start by right clicking on the project and rebuilding it.  If that works, odds are your project does not have a build definition set up (i.e. you have Debug/x86 in studio, but have not defined this for this project).

Comment: plz can u be more specific how can i check debug is defined in project or not

Comment: Sure - First, verify that a right click/build makes debugging reappear.  If this is the case, right click on your solution and select 'Batch Build'.  Here you will see your projects, configuration, platform. and the solution configuration - also a checkbox to build.  Make sure you have configuration options that match your solution config with a checkbox checked otherwise it will not build and debugger will not work.

Comment: Here's an MSDN link too!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/169az28z(v=VS.80).aspx